# How to set the font size of the text shown in input (not in drop down) for the combo box in Kendo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

I created a combo box and I am able to increase the drop down font size by styling the template, but I am not able to modify font size using **.k-input**  even  after setting the style, it is not changing, here I created the jsfiddle.

```
<input id="combobox" />

$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  index: 0,
  dataTextField: "text",
  dataValueField: "id", 
  dataSource: {
  data: [{id:1,text:"One"},{id:2,text:"Two"}]
  },
  template: "<span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:26pt'> #= data.text # </span>",
});
```

Style

```
.k-input {  
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-size:26pt; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z4rwQ/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set !important like below.

```
.k-input {  
    font-weight:bold !important; 
    font-size:26pt !important; 
}
```